# Tensorflow: Replacement for tf.nn.rnn_cell._linear(input, size, 0, scope)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to get the SequenceGAN (https://github.com/LantaoYu/SeqGAN) from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.05473.pdf to run.
After fixing the obvious errors, like replacing `pack` with `stack`, it still doesn't run, since the highway-network part requires the `tf.nn.rnn_cell._linear` function:

```
# highway layer that borrowed from https://github.com/carpedm20/lstm-char-cnn-tensorflow
def highway(input_, size, layer_size=1, bias=-2, f=tf.nn.relu):
    """Highway Network (cf. http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.00387).

    t = sigmoid(Wy + b)
    z = t * g(Wy + b) + (1 - t) * y
    where g is nonlinearity, t is transform gate, and (1 - t) is carry gate.
    """
    output = input_
    for idx in range(layer_size):
        output = f(tf.nn.rnn_cell._linear(output, size, 0, scope='output_lin_%d' % idx)) #tf.contrib.layers.linear instad doesn't work either.
        transform_gate = tf.sigmoid(tf.nn.rnn_cell._linear(input_, size, 0, scope='transform_lin_%d' % idx) + bias)
        carry_gate = 1. - transform_gate

        output = transform_gate * output + carry_gate * input_

    return output
```

the `tf.nn.rnn_cell._linear` function doesn't appear to be there anymore in Tensorflow 1.0 or 0.12, and I have no clue what to replace it with. I can't find any new implementations of this, or any information on tensorflow's github or (unfortunately very sparse) documentation.

Does anybody know the new pendant of the function?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: why doesn't tf.contrib.layers.linear work for you?

Comment: Is this function still contained in tf1.8?

Answer (score 4):

I met this error while using SkFlow's TensorFlowDNNRegressor.
The first time I saw the answer of ruoho ruots, I am a bit confused. 
But the next day I realized what he meant.

Here is what I do:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn_cell_impl
```

replace `tf.nn.rnn_cell._linear` with `rnn_cell_impl._linear`

Answer (score 2):

With version 1.0, stuff has moved all around. I've had similar hunts updating `tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell` to `tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell`.

For your case `tf.nn.rnn_cell._linear` now lives in `tf.contrib.rnn.python.ops.core_rnn_cell_impl` as well as the definition of the `BasicRNNCell`. Checking the [BasicRNNCell docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/BasicRNNCell) and [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py#L113-L118), we see at L113-L118 the use of _linear.

```
  def __call__(self, inputs, state, scope=None):
    """Most basic RNN: output = new_state = act(W * input + U * state + B)."""
    with _checked_scope(self, scope or "basic_rnn_cell", reuse=self._reuse):
      output = self._activation(
          _linear([inputs, state], self._num_units, True))
    return output, output
```

the _linear method is defined at [line 854](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py#L854) as a:
`Linear map: sum_i(args[i] * W[i]), where W[i] is a variable.`

Good luck!

Comment: I tried this solution on v 1.0 but got 
`AttributeError: type object 'BasicRNNCell' has no attribute '_linear'`

Comment: It is actually _defined_ in another file. Please see my answer for the correct code location.

Comment: I referenced the `tf.contrib.rnn.python.ops.core_rnn_cell_impl` but you're right, I wasn't clear that the `BasicRNNCell` and  `linear` both live in this file.  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py Good catch. I'll update my Answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of ruoho ruotsi is almost correct:
Yet, the *definition* of `linear` is not located in `tf.contrib.rnn.basicRNNCell`, but in `tf.contrib.rnn.python.ops.rnn_cell`, or `tf.contrib.rnn.python.ops.core_rnn_cell_impl`, respectively.

You can find their source code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9967bf6702153631e27f52ac95ab822f73fe758d/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9967bf6702153631e27f52ac95ab822f73fe758d/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py).

Comment: Not in version 1.2

Comment: This was valid for versions 1.0 and 1.1 only. They (at that time) said they would move the functions to other places in a later release, which is probably what happened in 1.2

Answer (score 1):

To solving this problem,we can define a linear() function.

```
def linear(input_, output_size, scope=None):
    '''
    Linear map: output[k] = sum_i(Matrix[k, i] * args[i] ) + Bias[k]
    Args:
        args: a tensor or a list of 2D, batch x n, Tensors.
    output_size: int, second dimension of W[i].
    scope: VariableScope for the created subgraph; defaults to "Linear".
    Returns:
    A 2D Tensor with shape [batch x output_size] equal to
    sum_i(args[i] * W[i]), where W[i]s are newly created matrices.
    Raises:
    ValueError: if some of the arguments has unspecified or wrong shape.
    '''

    shape = input_.get_shape().as_list()
    if len(shape) != 2:
        raise ValueError("Linear is expecting 2D arguments: %s" % str(shape))
    if not shape[1]:
        raise ValueError("Linear expects shape[1] of arguments: %s" % str(shape))
    input_size = shape[1]

    # Now the computation.
    with tf.variable_scope(scope or "SimpleLinear"):
        matrix = tf.get_variable("Matrix", [output_size, input_size], dtype=input_.dtype)
        bias_term = tf.get_variable("Bias", [output_size], dtype=input_.dtype)

    return tf.matmul(input_, tf.transpose(matrix)) + bias_term


def highway(input_, size, num_layers=1, bias=-2.0, f=tf.nn.relu, scope='Highway'):
    """Highway Network (cf. http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.00387).
    t = sigmoid(Wy + b)
    z = t * g(Wy + b) + (1 - t) * y
    where g is nonlinearity, t is transform gate, and (1 - t) is carry gate.
    """

    with tf.variable_scope(scope):
        for idx in range(num_layers):
            g = f(linear(input_, size, scope='highway_lin_%d' % idx))

            t = tf.sigmoid(linear(input_, size, scope='highway_gate_%d' % idx) + bias)

            output = t * g + (1. - t) * input_
            input_ = output

    return output
```

https://github.com/mkroutikov/tf-lstm-char-cnn/blob/7e899e6992cbf9a96e6d791e5d364eaaeec339a2/model.py

Answer (score 1):

tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl._linear now is at tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.core_rnn_cell._linear. And I prefer to use tf.layers.Dense to replace.
for example, change

```
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops import core_rnn_cell
core_rnn_cell._linear(states, length, bias=True)
```

to

```
tf.layers.Dense(units=length)(states)
```

I'm using tensorflow 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

Right now when you what to use `_linear` function, please use it like this:

`from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops import core_rnn_cell`

```
core_rnn_cell._linear(output, size)
```

Here is the link of its corresponding source file. [source file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell.py)

This is because after tf r1.5, the location of this function is changed.

When you are using tf r1.4 or even older version, please use it like this:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn_cell_impl

rnn_cell_impl._linear(output, size)
```

Here is the link of this older version of `_linear`. [source file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py)

As for `tf.nn.rnn_cell._linear`, this function is not available a long time ago.

Comment: For tensorflow version 1.15 this is what worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

As for now (1.2r0) you can replace it with 
[`tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=[inputs, state], num_outputs=self._num_units, biases_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0), activation_fn=None)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/fully_connected)
Note that `biases_initializer` defaults to all zeros for `_linear` and for no bias at all for `fully_connected`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `rnn_cell.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell._linear` instead of `_linear`